# Offsets retention with running consumers

Tags: apache-kafka

in Kafka doc `offsets.retention.minutes` is defined as

> After a consumer group loses all its
> consumers (i.e. becomes empty) its offsets will be kept for this
> retention period before getting discarded. For standalone consumers
> (using manual assignment), offsets will be expired after the time of
> last commit plus this retention period.

If a **running** consumer don't commit its offsets for **2 days** with `offsets.retention.minutes` set to **1 day**

Would the Consumer group offsets be discarded then ? so if the consumer restarts the offsets will depend on `auto.offset.reset` ?

or the `offsets.retention.minutes` config is applied only when consumers are down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offsets topic works like any other - it's keyed by group id and compacted based on this.

If there are no new events into the topic, then group information and offsets get discarded

Consumer heartbeats don't create new offset records, only offset commits do

Comment: If there are no new events into the topic before **offsets.retention.minutes** right ?